# calling a sling service on ajax call

Tags: ajax, service, aem, sling

I have written a Email Exchange service in my local and deployed it as a bundle into AEM6.So my service is available now as an sling service.

I have consumed it in my jsp as follows.

EmailService es - sling.getService(EmailService.class);

But now in Aem6 I need to call the service in sightly on a button click which will be done using an ajax call.

Can you please let me know how I can consume an sling service on an ajax call.

Thanks,
Esha

Answer (score 2):

You may not be able to call your service directly via AJAX since your service doesn't cater to requests.

You can write a `SlingServlet` that resolves to a path / resourceType which can Reference your EmailExchange service, or access any content node whose script uses your EmailExchange service via sling.getService()

```
@SlingServlet(paths="/bin/emailexchange.servlet", methods="POST")
public Class EmailExchangeServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    @Reference
    private EmailService emailService;

    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest req, SlingHttpServletResponse res) {
        // do your stuff 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep separation of concerns:

- **Services** provide data/implementations inside of the application server (also happen to be testable at build time outside of AEM/CQ5).  These should provide business logic/rules, but generally avoid rendering implementation.
- **Servlets** respond to HTTP requests, and ideally wrap a call to a service, to keep their code clean.  The servlet can determine if the response needs to be JSON, HTML, XML or other
- **Components** JSP's (and Sightly) should generally act as a template for the response.  They can also call Services directly to perform business logic.
- **AJAX** is an HTTP request that can interact with the path of either a servlet or a component to get the (typically) JSON or HTML response.

In this light, your AJAX should POST to a Servlet, which can call the Service.